# Proper way to space floating left characters

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML/CSS:

```css
.wrapper { border: 1px solid blue; height: auto; width: 830px; }
.feature_wrapper { float: left; width: 395px; margin: 10px; height: auto; }
.feature_wrapper img { float: left; margin-right: 10px; }
.feature_wrapper h3 { }
.feature_wrapper p { overflow: hidden; text-align: justify; }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class='feature_wrapper'>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/134x134">

            <h3>SAMPLE HEADER</h3>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc dictum porttitor mi, non tincidunt lorem iaculis nec. Vestibulum vel facilisis ante. Sed rutrum vulputate lectus, at fermentum nisi consectetur sit amet. Vivamus ultricies et dolor ut viverra. Nulla in nisi blandit, egestas neque in, rhoncus erat. Sed vitae euismod enim. Pellentesque varius sodales elementum. Nulla ut ligula consectetur massa porttitor pharetra. Morbi et ultrices enim, a finibus enim.</p>
        </div>

        <div class='feature_wrapper'>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/134x134">

            <h3>SAMPLE HEADER</h3>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc dictum porttitor mi, non tincidunt lorem iaculis nec. Vestibulum vel facilisis ante. </p>
        </div>

        <div class='feature_wrapper'>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/134x134">

            <h3>SAMPLE HEADER</h3>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc dictum porttitor mi, non tincidunt lorem iaculis nec. Vestibulum vel facilisis ante. Sed rutrum vulputate lectus, at fermentum nisi consectetur sit amet. Vivamus ultricies et dolor ut viverra. Nulla in nisi blandit, egestas neque in, rhoncus erat. Sed vitae euismod enim. Pellentesque varius sodales elementum. Nulla ut ligula consectetur massa porttitor pharetra. Morbi et ultrices enim, a finibus enim.</p>
        </div>

        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </div>
```

I want the ability to add as many elements as I need, and the text description for each will vary in size. How can I ensure the following:

- There is a proper margin-right for each left column
- The items will display properly
- The right column aligns with the the right edge

Comment: Can you be more specific about what kind of answer / help you're looking for? Is there a specific problem (Can you demonstrate)?

Comment: is hard to define "The items will display properly" what you need to do is test your code at two extreme e.g. long paragraph, and/or many wrapper section.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue you are having is because your wrapper is 830px wide and your feature_wrapper's are 410px wide including your margins. The total of the two feature_wrapper do not total more than 830px so when you float left, one does not drop below the next.

Either make your feature_wrapper 420px wide or create a container around all your feature_wrapper's and set the width to 410px.

Comment: This has been updated. feature_wrapper is 395px with a margin of 10px (making each section 415px). I still have all of the same issues...

Comment: Try adjusting feature_wrapper to 1px bigger (396px), if that doesn't work... I am a failure

Comment: I'm not sure If I'm explaining myself well. If you up feature_wrapper to 396px, each "feature_wrapper" div is on their own line. These should all float left in a 2 column layout very nicely, with nice margins and proper alignment.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I thought you wanted them all on the left side. And I am not sure what you are trying to do now :(